# GetMethodID method signature parameter

Tags: java, jar, jvm, java-native-interface

I have one function in Java with signature:

```
public static double[] getData()
```

And I want to get the method id of this function from the JNI interface using `GetMethodID` function.
For that I have mentioned in function signature parameter as following:

```
"()[D"
```

But this is not working and I get exception as Method Not Found(return null).

Comment: are you seeing NoSuchMethodError ?

Comment: when I call getmaethodID it's return 0.

Comment: have u looked at this http://www.cab.u-szeged.hu/WWW/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html

Comment: If answers really helped, you should accept them :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `GetStaticMethodID`, instead of `GetMethodID`, as your method is a static one.